# Can I use other open source libraries in the application contest?

Tags: application-development

I just found out about and started looking into the Ubuntu App Contest, and I wanted to double check the contest's stance on using open source libraries built by others that are freely available on the web.

I read through the rules and some of the other Q&As, and it sounds like using these libraries would not be allowed (since it could mean the app isn't built from scratch, and the library would not be in the Ubuntu archive - although I could bundle the library with the app), and I just wanted to verify this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You are free to use any libraries you choose as long as they are available to the user using the normal Ubuntu app installation method. This means that the library needs to be in the archives already, or included with your application.  As long as you can do one of these, the application is admissible for the App Showdown contest.  Be aware that your entry will be judged only on the code you wrote and the value it adds on top of the libraries you are using.